# How can I find the path a sample took down the decision tree using the DecisionTree class in Accord.NET

Tags: c#, machine-learning, decision-tree, accord.net

I am trying to find out the path a sample took down a DecisionTree I have created in Accord.NET but I am not sure how to do this. I have looked through the documentation and couldn't find out how to do this but as Accord.NET is used for machine learning I'm sure this functionality is available. It would be most useful to get totals of the paths taken from cross validation data, however if this is not possible then finding the path taken for new samples after the tree has been built could still work.

Below is an example of how I build a new decision tree and test a new sample:

```
C45Learning c45 = new C45Learning();
var c45Tree = c45.Learn(input, output);
int[] predicted = c45Tree.Decide(testSamples);
```